# Adaptive figure size in rmarkdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I have built an automatic report in RMarkdown. The problem is that images in this report can have varying size and therefore the relative size of the element inside changes based on the number of items in the axis:

[image]

[image]

(ok in this case the two images are totally different but it is just to show what I mean)

Is there a way to fix only some parameters, like resolution, or just one dimension, let the other dimension to vary according to the elements in order to keep the element size fixed?

Thanks

Comment: What type of document is your output? If it's HTML, you can use a Bootstrap template or some CSS sizing; if it's a PDF, that's more tricky

Comment: worse: .docx or rarely pdf

Comment: I find that I get the most control over my graphics when I write them to their own pdf file (one file per graphic) and then I import the graphic into the document I'm making with knitr.  For example, in my R code I have: `pdf(file="thisplot.pdf"); <code to make plot>; dev.off()` and in my knitr file I have `\includegraphics{"thisplot.pdf"}`.